# send data from android to php and php store a Sequence of ? in mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, unicode

I am using the following code to send data from my application to a PHP script on my server:

```
postList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PType", TxtWeight.getText().toString()));

String StrURL="http://chacho.comuv.com/android/insert_pistachio_sell.php";
myJsonObject=JP.store_And_Feedback("PType",SpnPistachio.getSelectedItem().toString()));
DefaultHttpClient DHC=new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("StrURL");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postList));
```

The following PHP code will store the received data in my database:

```
<?php
    require_once "./includes/DB_Connect.php"
    $PType=$_POST['PType'];

    $SQL="INSERT INTO  sell (ptype)VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($PType)."')";
    $Result=mysql_query($SQL);
?>
```

But data is saved in the database like "??????????"

I have searched a lot but I have not found a way to make this work properly.

Comment: I don't see in your code that you add the `Ptype` key-value pair to the postList list.  Are you writing the PWeight to the database? If so does that get sent via the POST request correctly?

Comment: it was just a typeing problem;i correct it

Comment: Are all characters being converted to `?` or just non-ASCII ones? For consistent Unicode support you should use UTF-8 on both sides: use `new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postList, "UTF-8")` at the client, `mysql_set_charset('utf-8')` at the app server and UTF-8-collated tables at the db server.

Comment: thank you a lot @bobince; new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postList, "UTF-8") slove my Problem and every thing work OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first i'm thank you from @bobince for help

1- in mysql set collection of field to "utf8_persian_ci"

2- in php code after connect to db run this code

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

3- in android code use UTF-8 encode like this code

```
new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postList, "UTF-8")
```

data will save correctly on your mysql database

Comment: Prefer `mysql_set_charset('utf-8')` over `SET NAMES`. The latter does not correctly update the encoding information used by `mysql_real_escape_string`, making it effectively the same as `mysql_escape_string`.

Comment: @bobince thank you again;i am just use mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); in php script and use new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postList, "UTF-8") in android application and remove mysql_real_escape_string from php script; every thing work perfect :)

Comment: Don't remove `mysql_real_escape_string`, you need it to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities! (In general, you are better off using `mysqli` or PDO together with parameterised queries so that you don't have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` explicitly each time, but if you are sticking with `mysql` then this SQL-escaping is essential.)